# Where do you set retention for ScheduleLog files?

Tags: sharepoint-server, logging

On this SharePoint 2013 farm I see `ScheduleLog-yyyymmdd.txt` files going back for years.  They are in the same folder as the ULS logs.  Sample content is like:

```
20-11-2019 00:00:57                   Verbose   Calling service  xxxx
20-11-2019 00:00:57                   Verbose   Schedule completed successfully
... every 10 minutes
```

So just wondering where you go to set the retention for these, or do you just have to delete the old ones once in a while?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I did not find these ScheduleLog files in my environment. This could be related with the log level in the settings.

Since they are in the same folder as the ULS logs. I think the rentention setting for uls logs also works for these files. Just go to CA-> Diagnostic Logging, set the retention for them:
[image]

Comment: Interesting that you don't have them in your environment.  I thought they may be coming from the job scheduler.  Unfortunately, my settings are like yours for ULS logs, just a different path.  ULS logs are pruned at 14 days, but the other go back for years.